# shibd_Default service cannot be started

Tags: shibboleth, service-provider, start-stop-daemon

While working on configuring the Shibbolet SP, I had to stop and start the shibd service many times after reconfiguring the shibboleth2.xml file.
first it worked ok, but then I couldn't start it again!

when running this command on cmd `C:\>net start shibd_default`, I got the following:

```
The Shibboleth 2 Daemon <Default> service is starting.
The Shibboleth 2 Daemon <Default> service could not be started.

The service did not report an error.
```

and when attempting to run it from Control Panel > Services > Administrative Tools , I got this error

```
   The Shibboleth 2 Daemon <Default> service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs.
```

I've re-installed the Shibboleth SP to overcome this problem, but still getting this error!

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check your log files at C:\opt\shibboleth-sp\var\log\shibboleth for errors.

IF there is a XML configuration error, the service won't load properly.

I Got an error similar to the one below:

```
ERROR Shibboleth.Config : error while loading resource (C:/opt/shibboleth-sp/etc/shibboleth/shibboleth2.xml): XML error(s) during parsing, check log for specifics
2013-05-13 10:59:13 FATAL Shibboleth.Config : caught exception while loading configuration: XML error(s) during parsing, check log for specifics
```

Comment: Yes that's totally true, I was able to solve it earlier by changing the shibboleth2.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similiar issue with configuraiton while trying to use Shibboleth version 3.4 in Docker container on Debian OS. Ended up testing configuration file for problems with:

```
/usr/sbin/shibd -t
```

This gave me hints on where the problem was.